# Socket em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, tcp

Estou fazendo a disciplina de redes e computadores e estou com problema na questão seguinte:

**Utilizando TCP, implemente um servidor que ofereça duas
funcionalidades: uppercase e daytime. O cliente, ao enviar uma
mensagem ao servidor, deve receber como resposta a mensagem em
letras maiúsculas e a hora em que o servidor recebeu sua solicitação.**

Bem, não estou conseguindo utilizar a função **upper()** no servidor. segue abaixo o meu código.

TCPServer.py

```python
from socket import *  

serverPort = 3000

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

#atribui a porta ao socket criado
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))    

#aceita conexões com no máximo um cliente na fila 
serverSocket.listen(1)

print('The server is ready to receive')


while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()         

    #recebe a mensagem do cliente em bytes
    mensagem = connectionSocket.recv(1024)     



    #envio tbm deve ser em bytes
    mensagem = mensagem.upper()
    connectionSocket.send(mensagem)

    connectionSocket.close()
```

TCPClient.py

```python
from socket import *   

serverName = 'localhost'

mensagem = "gustavo"

serverPort = 3000


clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))


#a mensagem deve estar em bytes antes de ser enviada ao buffer de transmissão
clientSocket.send(mensagem.encode())


#recebe a resposta do servidor
clientSocket.recv(1024)

#devemos converter a mensagem de volta para string antes de imprimí-la
print('Resposta:' , mensagem)

#fecha a conexão
clientSocket.close()
```

Bem, o que está acontecendo no meu código, vc deve estar se perguntando! bem, ele conecta o servidor normalmente e a saida do cliente não está maiúscula.

Gostaria de ajuda para utilizar o UPPERCASE no servidor TCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na linha 20 onde está o `clientSocket.recv(1024)`, você não passou a resposta para a variável `mensagem`. Logo, o que era imprimido era a mensagem que você enviou e não a que recebeu.

Eu sei que não está relacionado à sua pergunta, mas não se esqueça de decodificar a string ao recebê-la do método `recv`, caso contrário, poderá obter vários erros no seu código.

## Código correto do cliente:

```
from socket import *   

serverName = 'localhost'

mensagem = "gustavo"

serverPort = 3000


clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))


#a mensagem deve estar em bytes antes de ser enviada ao buffer de transmissão
clientSocket.send(mensagem.encode())


#recebe a resposta do servidor
msg = clientSocket.recv(1024).decode()

#devemos converter a mensagem de volta para string antes de imprimí-la
print('Resposta:' , msg)

#fecha a conexão
clientSocket.close()
```